# Emulator not showing in Android 4.0

Tags: android, emulation, virtualization, processor, amd-processor

I have tried to install the emulator from the Intel Emulator for Windows via SDK tools but it gives me an error all the time. I have an AMD processor which has no virtualization so how can I make the emulator show in my Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

You should activate virtualization in your windows. See here for more details: https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003174386-How-can-I-enable-virtualization-VT-on-my-PC-